# How can I send a message to a specific channel using Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Right now, I want to make a logger bot that logs everything sent and sends that to a chat log. I have this code right now which is:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready!")
    await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(name = "Logging whatever you say"))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel("721085548868927560")
    sender_id = message.author.id
    message_content = message.content
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    else:    
        await channel.send("<@" + sender_id + "> said " + message_content)
client.run("Not your bot, so don't look at the API token")
```

Whenever it runs and someone says something, the error that comes out is

```
  File "C:\Users\ryany.SVCYINBOOK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "logger.py", line 15, in on_message
    await channel.send("<@" + sender_id + "> said " + message_content)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: `"721085548868927560"` - remove the `" "`

Comment: @Joshua Nixon whenever I do that a new error comes up 
```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryany.SVCYINBOOK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "logger.py", line 15, in on_message
    await channel.send("<@" + sender_id + "> said " + message_content)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Josh pointed out in the comments, [IDs/Snowflakes are ints in rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#snowflakes-are-int).

I'd recommend reading through the major changes in [rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#) so you'll be familiarised with how rewrite behaves. It'll also help you recognise the difference between async (v0.16.x, now deprecated) and rewrite (v1.x) code when looking online and you stumble upon examples of how to do things.

---

**References:**

- [Rewrite changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#)
- [Rewrite docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
- [`Client.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)

  [image]